# Status of Stored Procedure call from Agent job, when job is stopped

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

We have a clean-up job, which calls a stored procedure, which in turn deletes one day's worth of records for a log table. This job runs every five minutes and usually completes in less than 10 seconds. Sometimes, it take much longer, as long as 15 minutes. During such instances, the log table gets locked and subsequent transactions timeout, till the job completes.

In order to address this, we came up with this solution -

1) Remove the scheduling of the existing job

2) Create a new job, to call the original job

3) Schedule the new job to run every 5 minutes

4) See below code of the new job

```
    DECLARE @JobToRun NVARCHAR(128) = N'OM_EDU_Purge logs'    
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @JobToRun
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J 
                  JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity A 
                        ON A.job_id=J.job_id 
                  WHERE J.name=@JobToRun 
                        AND A.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
                        AND A.stop_execution_date IS NULL
                )
            BEGIN -- job is running or finishing (not idle)
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name=@JobToRun                   
                -- could log info, raise error, send email etc here
            END
```

This seems to work fine and stops the job if it is still running after 20 seconds. However, since the job calls a stored procedure, here is my question:

When the job is stopped, will it also terminate the stored procedure that is executing?

Comment: No matter how I try, I am unable to format the code. Wonder what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you query gets stuck because the log table being updated or creating records concurrently with you delete statement. So you might try to lock the table while delete statement execution. update your procedure inside query like this exp: `delete from logs with(tablock)`

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the question. All I want to know is this - if a stored procedure is called from a job, will the execution stop, if the job is stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Here, a stored proc is just calling another nested stored proc. So no, stored proc won't be stopped. The control will return to the calling stored proc. You should have sufficient error-handling in the proc to take care of scenarios where the called sproc errors out.